# Tabulate incoming table information in json format as dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Output from my table.py file is as follows. My goal is to create a table in dataframe format using the information from here. (I caught the values of the tables in different formats in the pdf file). values contain information corresponding to rows or columns. The other alignment information is the information returned from the csv about their location in the pdf file.[image]now i need to tabulate them in dataframe but i couldn't find an easy way. I need your help.

{"returnData": [{"value": "Art.", "left": 123, "top": 445, "width": 16, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1,"prob": 0.8870015740394592},{"value": "Nr.", "left": 143, "top": 445, "width": 12, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.8796614408493042}, {"value": "Beschreibung", "left": 197, "top": 446, "width": 72, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9776557683944702}, {"value": "Kolli", "left": 501, "top": 448, "width": 25, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.8893064260482788}, {"value": "Inhalt", "left": 531, "top": 448, "width": 30, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9761049747467041}, {"value": "Menge", "left": 593, "top": 449, "width": 30, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9946377873420715},{"value": "Preis", "left": 665, "top": 449, "width": 20, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.974210262298584},{"value": "€", "left": 689, "top": 449, "width": 4, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9806452393531799},
{"value": "Betrag", "left": 743, "top": 450, "width": 30, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9663920998573303},{"value": "€", "left": 778, "top": 450, "width": 5, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9893004298210144},...]}

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy enough with `json_normalize`.

When `json_string` is the string you mentioned, try:

```
import pandas as pd
json_string = {
    "returnData":[
         {"value": "Art.", "left": 123, "top": 445, "width": 16, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1,"prob": 0.8870015740394592},
         {"value": "Nr.", "left": 143, "top": 445, "width": 12, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.8796614408493042},
         {"value": "Beschreibung", "left": 197, "top": 446, "width": 72, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9776557683944702},
         {"value": "Kolli", "left": 501, "top": 448, "width": 25, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.8893064260482788},
         {"value": "Inhalt", "left": 531, "top": 448, "width": 30, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9761049747467041},
         {"value": "Menge", "left": 593, "top": 449, "width": 30, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9946377873420715},
         {"value": "Preis", "left": 665, "top": 449, "width": 20, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.974210262298584},
         {"value": "€", "left": 689, "top": 449, "width": 4, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9806452393531799},
         {"value": "Betrag", "left": 743, "top": 450, "width": 30, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9663920998573303},
         {"value": "€", "left": 778, "top": 450, "width": 5, "height": 14, "pageNo": 1, "prob": 0.9893004298210144}
     ]
}

pd.json_normalize(json_string['returnData'])
```

returns:

```
value           left    top width   height  pageNo  prob
Art.            123     445 16      14      1       0.887002
Nr.             143     445 12      14      1       0.879661
Beschreibung    197     446 72      14      1       0.977656
Kolli           501     448 25      14      1       0.889306
Inhalt          531     448 30      14      1       0.976105
Menge           593     449 30      14      1       0.994638
Preis           665     449 20      14      1       0.974210
€               689     449 4       14      1       0.980645
Betrag          743     450 30      14      1       0.966392
€               778     450 5       14      1       0.989300
```

Since these are column values, you can determine the left-rightbound of a column. f.e. all Art. Nr. values will be between ±123 and ±197, Beschreibung between ±197 and ±501. So you can map the following data according to that logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting TypeError with this method.
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, try my exact code snippet

Comment: it's fixed, but what I need to do is to create a dataframe like in the photo. The values given by value are my values in the rows and forming my columns. The left etc values just give their position in the pdf.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output, so include at least 1 row of actual data in it.